# Empty line as SED end range pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed

Trying to print lines with matched text within the range. This works fine if I use --START-- and --END-- as a pattern for range.

```
$ sed -n '/--START--/{:a;N;/--END--/!ba; /Device=A/p}' file
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
--END--
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
--END--
```

But if I replace --END-- with empty line it stops working

```
file:
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum

--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf


$ sed -n '/--START--/{:a;N;/^$/!ba; /Device=A/p}' file
```

I guess sed doesn't recognize empty line pattern within curly braces.
Please advise how to fix command to use empty line pattern instead of --END--

Comment: Are there spaces in the  "blank" liines? `od -bc file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that - regardless of whether it is in a braced subexpression or not - `/pattern/` is matched against the entire pattern space. As soon as you have a multiline pattern (via the use of `N` for example), it is impossible for `^$` to match (there will be at least a newline character between `^` and `$`).

GNU sed has a **M**ultiline mode extension that

> causes ^ and $ to match respectively (in addition to the normal
> behavior) the empty string after a newline, and the empty string
> before a newline

```
$ sed -n '/--START--/{:a;N;/^$/M!ba; /Device=A/p}' file
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
```

Otherwise, if you want to match a trailing empty line in a multiline pattern, you should be able to use `\n$` explicitly ex.:

```
$ sed -n '/--START--/{:a;N;/\n$/!ba; /Device=A/p}' file
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
```

Comment: thank you for clear explanation